# How to do bluetooth pair between raspberry pi and phone from script?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, asterisk, bluez

I want to connect my phone to asterisk, who installed on the rbpi3 with chan_mobile.
I want to do web-interface for connect.
First step its scan for phones - its simple. Many hundreds path.
Second step - pairing intit. For send request from rbpi to phone (or revert, nevermind)
I have trouble with this step.
Old bluez (<5) have simple-agent and i can do pair with shell command:

```
bluetooth-agent --adapter hciX _pin_ mac_for_pair
```

Actual bluez(5.47 on this moment) dont have analog.
Only interactive bluetoothctl console.
I'll try to search libs for node js, python, but i dont see method of pair request init(or accept, if init from phone). 
Can you help me? In fact, I need any path suitable for use in a script in which I want to pass the adapter and the target.

Answer (score 0):

bluez has DBus API's to perform operations you need. See doc/ directory from bluez source. Go through doc/adapter-api.txt, doc/device-api.txt and doc/agent-api.txt files. These document files gives you fair understanding on scanning for bluetooth devices, running agent for authentication and pairing with your phone.

You can get sample codes for the DBus API's in the test directory of bluez source. See test/test-discovery and test/test-agent code to understand how to start a bluetooth scan using bluez DBus API. All the sample codes in test directory are in python and some scripts can be directly used in your application.

The bluetooth-agent you mentioned is an agent for authentication that is available with older bluez versions. You can create your own agent; see test/simple-agent python script in bluez source directory.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a C function in this [post](http://prabhakarlad.blogspot.co.uk/2017/09/bluez5-pairing-devices-tricks.html) , you could just easily convert it into a script or just compile the C code and call it from the script.